# Advice on how to handle an equal with less experience bossing me around

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I have a colleague that has been with the company for 2 years and I have been here for 5 years. He has no degree and has been tapped to be the next Test Technician, he has been given the responsibility to write a testplan for the next build of a product and basically gets to tell me and other technicians what to do.

I was not that bothered before but the guy can't wait to order me about and make me look stupid. This is all down to my boss who basically wants to destroy my life.

I need advise on how to handle this, the guy is the same grade as me and knows nothing about electronics.

Comment: Based off your other questions, you really don't have good luck with this role :/

Comment: `I need advise on how to handle this` What is your goal?

Comment: *"but the guy can't wait to order me about and make me look stupid."* - Don't let it get to that point. Make sure your product is in good order before giving it to the tester. He might be mean but if he's catching bad things that really need to get fixed, then that is good on him, he's doing what he's hired to do.

Comment: Kinda vague question ,few details are missing, But based on what is present - your next stop is HR regarding boss
Coworker getting the assignment is not in your power to change or get it for yourself

Answer (score 9):

There are several aspects that don't click in your story.

You claim you have been assigned a Test Manager who has less seniority with the company than you do. This in itself should not be a problem, as it is your manager's job and responsibility to assign team management roles. Even if your colleague is a shaved ape (I.E: incompetent with no communication skills whatsoever), it's still not your job to contest his authority. He may be younger, dumber and less skilled than your are, but he is your manager's choice. If you have a problem with your manager's choice, feel free to take it up with him in a 1 on 1 meeting. Do not take your dissatisfaction for not being first choice for the role to your colleague. Take it up to the manager or the manager of the manager.

Furthermore, you seem to be upset by the way he chose to do his job (managing test plan creation and execution). Please note that this is HIS job, not yours, so he will be rewarded or punished for how it ends up being done. If his manner of communicating tasks to you and the test team is unfair, upsetting or inept, make notes of it and address them in a meeting with him and his boss. Make sure your arguments are full-proof and that there's nothing you could have done to make it better (or that he ignored all your requests for improvements).

Why would you assume he wants to make you look stupid? Maybe he has poor communication skills, or he simply doesn't know what to do. Try telling him his choice of relaying tasks is less than optimal and you are ready to help him improve if he wants it. Some technical aspects may be helped with your expertise, but communication gaps are usually outside of the scope of normal work relations.

Answer (score 1):

If your boss wants to destroy you life, your problem is not with this coworker but with your boss. At this point you should maybe get a lawyer or get out. If it happens with this coworker it will probably happen with others.

Now to address the issue with your coworker. If he's not your direct superior he should not be able to "boss" you. If he give you tasks, but you are already working on something else that you actual superior ask you to do, ask your coworker to confirm with your superior that you have to do it and when. Always be polite when doing so.

> Hello [coworker], I'm sorry but I'm already working on X and can't help you with Y. If you really need Y to be done, please contact [superior] to agree that I should do Y before X.

Now if your superior is your boss that want to destroy your life just confirm once with him that all task from your coworker are priorities above else and document it (writing or email) to protect you.